# Why doesn't my bot add rank to users? [DISCORD.JS

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

As in the question, I have a problem with a bot that won't add ranks, I don't know why, I think I'm doing everything right.

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
WelcomeUser(guildMember)});
```

The bot only sends an embed to the welcome chat, but does not rank the user

```
    function WelcomeUser(usr){

    usr.roles.add(userRoleID);

    let welcomeChan = bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === welcomeChanID);
    let userAvatar = usr.user.avatarURL();

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(usr.user.tag + " welcome in our server!")
        .setColor("#ffff00")
        .setThumbnail(userAvatar)
        .setFooter('RollerBot by flanktus', "https://i.imgur.com/M2NNoC9.png")
        .setDescription("We hope you will have a nice time");

    welcomeChan.send(embed);
    welcomeChan.send(`${usr.user}`)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean adding a specific role to a user?

Comment: Is the role ID outside the scope of the function?

Comment: @PerplexingParadox Yeah, exacly

Comment: @Radnerus Yes, but even when it is in the function it doesn't work

Comment: You have to get the `member` property, not the `user` property. To fix this, you could simply do `usr.member.roles.add(userRoleID);`. But this is assuming that `userRoleID` is the actual role itself, which I suspect it isn't. Check [this](https://anidiots.guide/understanding/roles#add-a-member-to-a-role) for more info.

Comment: @PerplexingParadox what? `usr` is a GuildMember.

Comment: Oh, my bad, my brain instinctively thought `usr` meant `user`.

Comment: I believe then it's because you're using the role ID instead of the role object itself.

Comment: @flanktus is the roleID a valid ID? can you double check if it exists, and also exists in the correct guild?